# Get count of files in structure without recursion

Tags: java, file

Is it possible to get the total count of files inside a folder (and all sub* folders) without to iterate over all files, and go recursivly deeper?

i mean this is very easy indeed but maybe there is a better solution?

```
private int totalFileCounter = 0;

private void countFiles(File f) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        for (File fi : f.listFiles()) {
            countFiles(fi);
        }
    } else {
        totalFileCounter++;
    }
}
```

edit: okay maybe my question wasnt that good asked... i mean is there any functionality from java or the filesystem or something else that allows me to get the total count of file in O(1)? All the solutions if have now have runtime O(n).

Comment: No, you can't do it without recursion (except if you transform the recursion into a loop, but that's just hiding the recursion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the simplest solutions are the best.  I wouldn't use a field to compute the result of what should be a function. If the method were called from two threads at once you can get incorrect results.

```
static int countFiles(File f) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (File fi : f.listFiles()) 
            sum += countFiles(fi);
        return sum;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: i'll accept your solution for code cleanness and style :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a [`Queue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) to do an iterative [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Here's an example (untested):

```
private void countFiles(File f) {
    Queue<File> queue = new LinkedList<File>();
    queue.add(f);
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
      File file = queue.poll();
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        queue.addAll(Arrays.asList(file.listFiles()));
      } else {
        totalFileCounter++;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would make `totalFileCounter` a local variable.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I agree, but OP's method return type is `void` so I suppose he always wants to update the instance variable `totalFileCounter`.

Comment: in my case thats not so critical... the method is not forced to be thread safe but its always better if it is :)

Answer (score 0):

Can this [Apache Commons API](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d,%20boolean%29) serve your purpose. It returns the `Collection<File>`

Comment: but i think it will internally also do a kind of recursion / stack / queue to provide this collection? Then it will also run in O(n) and will be very time consuming on some folders...